# tlmgr, the maximum number of allowed clients already connected

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

What is the meaning of the below statement incurred when invoking tlmgr install:

```
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 401 Sorry, the maximum number of allowed clients (10) are already connected. (for ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final/archive/biblatex.tar.xz)
```

It gives an impression that there will be infinitely the maximum number of allowed clients connected and thus you will never be able to install your package.

---

By switching to another mirror, as suggested, I run into another problem related to checksum:

tlmgr --repository http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet install feynmf (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, line 5579.

I reported this problem in another post

[tlmgr, changing repository, containerchecksum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332403/tlmgr-changing-repository-containerchecksum)

Comment: Use a mirror; `tug.org` is very likely to be overloaded. What does `tlmgr option repository` say? In my case I get `http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet`. What happens if you use `tlmgr` with the option `--repository http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet`, or any other mirror close to you? See http://ctan.org/mirrors for a list of mirrors.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.