# tlmgr, changing repository, containerchecksum

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I change tlmgr repository

```
sudo tlmgr option repository http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

Then when trying to install a package, e.g.

```
tlmgr install logreq
```

I get the following error:

```
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955...

/usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5579
```

How can I make this work?

---

By installing texlive from scratch as described in tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html and (IMPORTANT) not forgetting to change the path as described in the mentioned link I access the TexLive 2016 version.

tex --version

TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)

However, the checksum problem persists.

Comment: you are using an old (perhaps texlive 2015) tlmgr and trying to update from a texlive 2016 repository. Do not update from texlive 2015 to 2016, just install a fresh texlive 2016

Comment: Upgrading to TeXLive 2016 (=fresh install, see https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) is faster than trying to fix these errors. Not counting troubles later on resulting from old packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you run the `vanilla` search I suggested? As I say, you have an upstream TeX Live install and a non-upstream one. You need to eliminate the latter.

Comment: Yes, I did. But reinstalling everything seems to be an overkill.